# Remove duplicates based on specific column

Tags: regex, linux, text, awk, sed

I do have a big text file in the following format on my Linux CentOS 7.

```
430004, 331108, 075, 11, 19, Chunsuttiwat Nattika
431272, 331108, 075, 11, 19, Chunsuttiwat Nattika
435979, 335086, 803, 6, 19, ANNI BRENDA
436143, 335151, 545, 4, 23, Agrawal Abhishek
436723, 335387, 386, 2, 19, Bhati Naintara
438141, 325426, 145, 11, 19, Teh Joshua
```

I would like to remove duplicate lines including the origin if it matches on second column.

Expected Output:

```
435979, 335086, 803, 6, 19, ANNI BRENDA
436143, 335151, 545, 4, 23, Agrawal Abhishek
436723, 335387, 386, 2, 19, Bhati Naintara
438141, 325426, 145, 11, 19, Teh Joshua
```

Comment: if the duplicates are next to each other as shown in sample, then the best tool to use is `uniq`... few minutes of looking at `man uniq` and you'll be able to do it

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, how big is your file? show `wc -l yourfile`

Comment: well then, you can sort it first and then apply uniq command.. in both cases you can skip first column... assumes you do have those spaces after `,`

Comment: So, based on the values in column tow, you want to ged rid of the lines with a duplicate _and_ the origin?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, thanks for the "king" ) I'm just a humble human

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, thanks for kind words, I appreciate that

Comment: I guess you don't need anybody else's help..

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, see my update, but on big files - use EdMorton's solution, it'll go faster (Right now, EdMorton's approach and my approach gives the same number of lines - 441)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*:

***sort*** + ***uniq*** + ***awk*** pipeline:

```
sort -k2,2 file | uniq -f1 -c -w7 | awk '$1==1{ sub(/[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]*/,"",$0); print}'
```

---

- `sort -k2 -n file` - sort the file by the 2nd field numerically
- `uniq -f1 -c` - output lines with the number of occurrences (`-f1` - skips the 1st field in the file)
- `awk '$1==1{ $1=""; print}'` - print the lines which occur only once (`$1==1` - check for count value from `uniq` command)

Comment: I'm wondering why this also have the same result: `sort -k2 f | uniq -f3 -c | awk '$1==1 {$1=""; print}'`

Comment: @JohnGoofy, this `uniq -f3 -c` will skip the whole first 3 fields, starting processing from the 4th field

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, perhaps, they differ somehow. can you post those duplicate lines selectively?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I know, that's why I'm wondering, the output for the given result is always the same from `uniq -c -f1` to `uniq -c -f6`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, it's hard to read it in a comment. can you post in formatted view or via screeshot?

Comment: @EdMorton, I know about that space, about that `sub` and whatever else. I waited for the concrete OP's complaints

Comment: @JohnGoofy all the various `uniq`s produce the same result because in the posted sample input the lines that are identical in field 2 are also identical at every other field afterwards so it doesn't matter how many fields you skip **in this example** to get the expected output. In other words, it's a bad example wrt testing that a given solution works.

Comment: @EdMorton, that's the thing I can agree with: the sample is far from ideal. I've just came home, uploaded the actual OP's file (102038) and only now I see the issues

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, see my update, should work for your actual input file

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just use `-u` option... `sort -k2 file | uniq -u -f1` no need for further processing

Comment: @EdMorton no, `uniq -u` will print only unique lines.. here's a sample test `printf '1\n2\n1\n' | sort | uniq -u`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
#Input
awk '{R[i++]=$0;f=$1;$1="";N[$0]++;}
     END{for(i=0;i<NR;i++){
     temp=R[i];sub(/^[[:digit:]]*\, /,"",R[i]);
     if(N[" "R[i]]==1){print temp}}}' filename
#Output
435979, 335086, 803, 6, 19, ANNI BRENDA
436143, 335151, 545, 4, 23, Agrawal Abhishek
436723, 335387, 386, 2, 19, Bhati Naintara
438141, 325426, 145, 11, 19, Teh Joshua
```

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Your question is not at all clear.. My answer gives you the exact output you require.. What you mean by saying `it's keep duplicated`?

Comment: Did you mean to say if the name appears twice then the line shouldn't be printed?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next} c[$2]==1' file file
435979, 335086, 803, 6, 19, ANNI BRENDA
436143, 335151, 545, 4, 23, Agrawal Abhishek
436723, 335387, 386, 2, 19, Bhati Naintara
438141, 325426, 145, 11, 19, Teh Joshua
```

Comment: Yes I'm positive and you can see in my answer it producing exactly the output you asked for given the sample input you provided so idk why you'd say it's not doing anything. Hang on - is it possible that in your real input file you do not have a space after every comma so your input lines look like `438141,325426,145,11,19,Teh Joshua` instead of `438141, 325426, 145, 11, 19, Teh Joshua` as you show in your question? If so then none of the posted answers would work for you.